# Pass data from twig templete to controller by ajax call in shopware 6

Tags: ajax, shopware, shopware6

how do pass data from the Twig template to the controller by Ajax call in shopware 6?

By using this code I successfully called the controller with the route name "ajaxcall" by the ajax call but I didn't pass data into the controller.

```
    import HttpClient from 'src/service/http-client.service';
    import Plugin from 'src/plugin-system/plugin.class';

    export default class customPlugin extends Plugin {

    init() {
        this._client = new HttpClient();
        document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", this.displayDate);


    }
    displayDate() { 
        this._client = new HttpClient();
        this._client.get('/ajaxcall');
    }
  }
```

By using this method the controller was called successfully by js, but didn't post data from js to the controller.

your guidelines able to appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

get is no really valid thing to submit data, use post instread...

An example:

```js
this._httpClient.post('/ajaxcall', JSON.stringify({
            mykey: 'myValue',
            mySecondKey: 'mySecondValue',
        }), response => {
            // do something with response 
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,
Kindly tell me how to get that stringify value in controller.

Comment: `$request->get('mykey')` f.e.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't work for me.
if you have any other solution kindly tell me!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var data = new FormData();
data.append('key1',value1);
data.append('key2',value2);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) { // XMLHttpRequest.DONE == 4
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            // success
        }
        else if (xhr.status == 400) {
            
        }
        else {
            
        }
    }
};


xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    
};
xhr.send(data);
```